# Perl regex to match only if not followed by both patterns

Tags: regex, perl, expression, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to write a pattern match to only match when a string is not followed by both following patterns. Right now I have a pattern that I've tried to manipulate but I can't seem to get it to match correctly.

Current pattern:

```
/(address|alias|parents|members|notes|host|name)(?!(\t{5}|\S+))/
```

I am trying to match when a string is not spaced correctly but not if it is part of a larger word.

For example I want it to match,

```
host \t{4} something
```

but not,

```
hostgroup \t{5} something
```

In the above example it will match hostgroup and end up separating it into 2 separate words "host" and "group"

Match:

```
notes \t{4} something
```

but not,

```
notes_url \t{5} something
```

Using my pattern it ends up turning into:

```
notes \t{5} _url
```

Hopefully that makes a bit more sense.

Comment: When you say *"not followed by both following patterns"* do you mean "not followed by *either* of two patterns"? Is the requirement is that the word should be followed by fewer than five tabs?

Comment: Your goal is not clear at all.  If you're unable to articulate what you want clearly in words, at the very least you can edit the question to provide a lot of examples of things you DO want to match and strings you don't, and why.  Often this step will have the additional benefit of helping you realize the solution yourself, but at minimum it will help us advise you a lot better.

Comment: To answer the first question I want it to match when the first group is not followed by either of the second group. I am trying to align it to a standard of 5 tabs any of the strings in the first group so I want it to match and correct it is for instance there are only 4 tabs following or more than 5, however I also don't want it to try to do so if the first match is part of a larger word. Does that make a bit more sense? I apologize if the original explanation was a bit more unclear than what I intended.

Comment: You say you want a match for `"host\t\t\t\tsomething"` and for `"notes\t\t\t\t\tsomething"`. Are you sure that's right? The second one has `notes` followed by five tabs, and I thought you *didn't* want to match that.

Comment: Typo on my part. You're right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not at all clear what you want, but word boundaries will probably do what you ask.

Does this work for you?

```
/\b(address|alias|parents|members|notes|host|name)\b(?!\t{5})/
```

---

**Update**

Having understood your problem better, does this do what you want?

```
/\b(address|alias|parents|members|notes|host|name)\b(?!\t{5}(?!\t))/
```

Comment: Almost, but I am also trying to avoid it from matching if the first group is part of a larger word.

Comment: @user3486833: Try it. It does that.